# Explicitly specified file was ignored due to negative glob patterns in lint stage

Tags: next.js, husky, lint-staged

When tried to commit nextjs with nextauth, lint stage failed due to this error,

```
Explicitly specified file was ignored due to negative glob patterns: "c:/projects/project01/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts".
```

lint stage config in package.json,

```
 "lint-staged": {
    "**/*": "prettier --write --ignore-unknown"
  }
}
```

Is this error causing due to nextjs catch all route folder name with brackets?

Answer (score 1):

i have a same case

and according to what I read, you have to use a terminal other than Windows to solve this

please read this [prettier-isue](https://github.com/saoudi-h/prettier-issue/blob/main/README.md)

```
# Steps to Reproduce the Issue with Prettier
```

This document explains the steps you have taken so far in an attempt to reproduce an issue encountered with Prettier when dealing with files with special names.

### Step 1: Creating the Test Project

1. Using `npx create-next-app@latest` to create a Next.js project.
2. Selecting configuration options such as TypeScript, Tailwind CSS, and ESLint.

```bash
√ Would you like to use TypeScript? ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to use ESLint? ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to use Tailwind CSS? ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to use `src/` directory? ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to use App Router? (recommended) ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to customize the default import alias? ... No / Yes
√ What import alias would you like configured? ... @/*
```

### Step 2: Installing Prettier

1. Installing Prettier as a development dependency:

```
    npm install -D prettier
```

### Step 3: Creating a Test File

1. Creating the file `.src/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts`.
2. Adding simple TypeScript code to the test file.

### Step 4: Attempting to Run Prettier

1. Trying to run Prettier on the test file using the command: `npx prettier --write "./src/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts"`.
2. Receiving the error: `[error] Explicitly specified file was ignored due to negative glob patterns: "./src/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts".`.

### Step 5: Attempting to Escape Special Characters

1. Attempting to escape special characters in the file name `[...nextauth].ts` using different methods, including the caret ("^","`","") character in PowerShell.
2. No escape method succeeded in resolving the issue under Windows.

### Step 6: Testing with Zsh Terminal

1. Running the same command with a Zsh terminal: `npx prettier --write ./src/pages/api/auth/\[...nextauth\].ts`.
2. The command successfully works in Zsh after escaping the brackets.

### Step 7: Testing with Custom Command

1. Adding a custom command to the `package.json` file: `"format:fix": "prettier --write --ignore-path .gitignore ."`
2. The `npm run format:fix` command successfully formats all target files, including `[...nextauth].ts`.

### Step 8: Conclusion

Unfortunately, the issue persists under Windows, even after multiple attempts to escape special characters in the `[...nextauth].ts` file name. Prettier continues to reject the file due to negative glob patterns.

### My setup

generated with:

```
npx envinfo --system --binaries --npmPackages --markdown "next,react,prettier,typescript"
```

#### System:

- OS: Windows 10 10.0.22621
- CPU: (16) x64 AMD Ryzen 7 5800X 8-Core Processor
- Memory: 8.16 GB / 31.93 GB

#### Binaries:

- Node: 18.15.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
- Yarn: 1.22.19 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\yarn.CMD
- npm: 9.8.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
- pnpm: 8.6.12 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\pnpm.CMD

#### npmPackages:

- @types/node: 20.6.2 => 20.6.2
- @types/react: 18.2.21 => 18.2.21
- @types/react-dom: 18.2.7 => 18.2.7
- autoprefixer: 10.4.15 => 10.4.15
- eslint: 8.49.0 => 8.49.0
- eslint-config-next: 13.4.19 => 13.4.19
- next: 13.4.19 => 13.4.19
- postcss: 8.4.29 => 8.4.29
- prettier: ^3.0.3 => 3.0.3
- react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
- react-dom: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
- tailwindcss: 3.3.3 => 3.3.3
- typescript: 5.2.2 => 5.2.2

#### additional informations

(does not work on Windows with these terminals)

- PowerShell: Version 7.3.6
- cmd
- Git Bash

It worked on

- Ubuntu WSL (Zsh terminal).

Comment: But I don't get any errors when directly run prettier on the project with ```npx prettier --write .``` .Problem only cause when using with lint-staged. But I got a fix for that also and working fine in windows also.

Answer (score 0):

With this lint-stage config problem solved.

````
const isWin = process.platform === "win32"

module.exports = {
  "**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json}": (filenames) => {
    const escapedFileNames = filenames
      // this will wrap all "[" "]" square brackets with another square brackets ([ => [[]) so [...customer].tsx will be processed to [[]...customer[]].tsx
      .map(
        (filename) =>
          `"${isWin ? filename.replace(/\[|\]/g, "[$&]") : escape([filename])}"`
      )
      .join(" ")
    return [`prettier --write --ignore-unknown ${escapedFileNames}`]
  },
  "**/*.{json,md,mdx,css,html,yml,yaml,scss}": (filenames) => {
    const escapedFileNames = filenames
      .map(
        (filename) =>
          `"${isWin ? filename.replace(/\[|\]/g, "[$&]") : escape([filename])}"`
      )
      .join(" ")
    return [`prettier --write --ignore-unknown ${escapedFileNames}`]
  },
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

you can editor package.json

```js
"**/*.{js,jsx,tsx,ts,css,less,scss,sass}": [
    "prettier --write --no-error-on-unmatched-pattern"
]
```